# Two player game in iOS with GameCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center

Hello All,

I am working on a checkers game and I want to add the game center. It's a turn based game. I want to check the friend list of game center and I want to know who is busy, online, offline, play with my friend, etc. 
How Can I make it?

I learned with the official documention of apple. But is there any blog tutorial or doc file that can be helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good tutorial on the Ray Wenderlich blog: [How To Make A Simple Multiplayer Game with Game Center Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12)
It works with the Cocos2D framework instead of CocoaTouch but this is a very good tutorial to start with.

Comment: thanks..  this is in cocos2d, i need in cocoa touch.. And also include the second player from bluetooth connection.. please help me more.. Thanks...

Comment: Cocos2D is just a game framework for iPhone. The logic and the code for the game center are exactly the same. To work with the bluetooth you can check this tuto: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1